# Snubber capacitor VAC handling by frequency of C0G?

Tags: capacitor, snubber, ceramic

I'm looking for a suitable snubber capacitor (220 pf) for a boost converter.

The semiconductor manufacturer recommends some ceramic capacitors for this

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/212/KEM_C1035_C0G_PULSE_SMD-515563.pdf

The capacitor will have a stress of around 70kHz 800Vpp.
Even though the rated Vdc i 2000 V I'm a bit skeptic it will handle the 800 Vpp at 70 kHz.

Maybe there is something I don't know, I just know that film capacitors usually have a Vrms depending on frequency.

Hope someone could enlighten me

Comment: You're worried about the voltage, I'm **also** worried about the **current**. The cap's impedance at 70 kHz is about 10 kohm so 40 mA peak is flowing. That will result in power dissipation due to series resistance. It only says "Low ESR" in the datasheet but not **how low**. As no guarantees are given regarding high voltage behavior at 70 kHz or higher, I would choose a cap. that does give this information in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

Ceramic caps are great at handling spikes; in many applications people unwittingly use them as a second line of defense for ESD.  I wouldn't be uncomfortable using a 500V part for 800VPP (400V maximum instantaneous).  As far as the power dissipation goes, Kemet has a [fine tool](http://ksim.kemet.com/Ceramic/CeramicCapSelection.aspx) that will plot the ESR of your capacitor over frequency.  Unfortunately, that tool doesn't cover this series of caps.  However, there's not a huge difference among ceramic caps from competent manufacturers, and Murata has a similar part GRM32B7U3D221JW31 (2000V 220pF 1210) that [their fine tool](http://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us) says has an ESR under 0.1 ohms all the way to 499MHz.  I don't think you have anything to worry about.